# How it add a private child class its parent class from another file in C#

Tags: c#, class

I really like to simplify the code in each file and would like to create a child class inside its parent from another file. This way I don't need to have lots of child class's inside my parent class and make it pretty.

I can do eg:

```
    public class Parent
    {
        private class Child
        {

        }
    }
```

I don't want hundreds of lines of child classes inside my parent class.

I really want to do something like:

```
    //File1
    public class Parent
    {

    }
    //File2
    private class Parent.Child{

    }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as these are in the same assembly/project, use the [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) keyword.

File1.cs:

```
public partial class Parent
{
  // parent stuff
}
```

File2.cs:

```
public partial class Parent
{
  private class Child
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [partial class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx), like this:

```
// File1.cs
public partial class Parent
{
}

// File2.cs
public partial class Parent
{
    private class Child
    {
    }
}
```